# CSS nth-of-type(...) sector that is equivalent to n<5?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm wondering whether there is a CSS selector that is equivalent to

```
element:nth-of-type(1),
element:nth-of-type(2),
element:nth-of-type(3),
element:nth-of-type(4)
```

or more generally

```
element:nth-of-type(1),
element:nth-of-type(2),
.
.
.
element:nth-of-type(k)
```

I tried `nth-of-type(5-n)`, but that wasn't valid.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
:nth-of-type(-n+4)
```

Example:

```css
p:nth-of-type(-n+4) {
    background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
```

As [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) explains: The `:nth-of-type` CSS pseudo-class matches an element that has an+b-1 siblings with the same element name before it in the document tree, for a given positive or zero value for n, and has a parent element. Here we make a=-1 and b=4, which will select the elements 4, 3, 2, and 1.